# Debug TaskAgent in Windows Phone 8

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, background-task

I develop an app for Windows Phone 8 and use Task Agent. I need to debug code that used in Task Agent. I try to join the process in menu Debug - Join the process, but when I choose the right qualifier, the process list is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about BackgroundTaskAgent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot debug Background task agents the same way you debug normal windows phone projects. Here are some techniques used.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Background_Agents_Debugging_Tips_on_Windows_Phone

I have used the ShellToast successfully to debug my agents. IMPORTANT: Remember to remove/comment all those code you add before deploying, or use #IFDEF statements.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using PeriodicTask.

Comment: same answer holds true. Can you mark this as answer if you are satisfied with it?